# Restrict access to docker swarm (manager / configuration)

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, restriction

With docker v1.12.3 creating a swarm is as simple as

`docker swarm init --advertise-addr <MANAGER-IP>`

Is there a way to restrict access to certain 'areas' of the swarm. E.g. I create a manager on a specific machine with an static IP address and I want to give the registration/security token to other developers to join the swarm. But at this point my system get compromised meaning if I do not want that other people (by purpose/or not) demote or activate the manager.

Is there any solution to this? I could not find any solution to my question.

Thanks, Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, You give them `worker` join token. So they join as `workers`, and cant do anything.

Secondly, You can change the `token`, after they joined, so they cant join more systems.

And I think you need to review your intentions of the `swarm mode`, its actually intended to provide service availbality/scaling across multiple `docker hosts`. All those `hosts` should be managed by you, not your developers.

Promoting a node to Manager:
`docker node promote <node name>`

Promotes a `node` to `manager`. This command **targets a docker engine that is a manager** in the `swarm`.

[Source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_promote/).

Comment: I know if I create a swarm/manager I get an token which is used for other worker nodes to join the swarm. But if understand correctly the new worker is able to promote any other worker to a manager or e.g. activate my 'drained' manager easily with `docker node update --availability active manager1`. The way I see it that there is no restriction to do so or is there? ( Or can only directly accessed manager nodes change the swarm behaviors (manager/drain/activate)? )